# While creating new Rails Application

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openssl, rvm

Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/. Could not load OpenSSL. You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.

I am using mac OS 10.8.2

Comment: so what is the actual problem that you are facing ??

Comment: It looks like the answer you might be looking for is in the message you copy/pasted. What is your question?

Comment: I changed the https into http but still it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There is a new experimental way of dealing with dependencies in RVM => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/pull/1544 :

```
rvm get branch /features/improved_dependencies
rvm pkg remove
rvm remove 1.9.3
rvm install 1.9.3
```